# Changing content of button removes style WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Changing the content image of a button makes it ignore any previously defined layout properties.

What I suspect is the fact that upon changing `this.Content` in the Button click event, it modifies:

```
<Button>
     Everything found between these tags.
</Button>
```

And as my Style is inside those tags, it overrides it.

Here is the code for record:

```
private void ChangeImageFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Image Files|*.png;*.jpeg;*.tiff;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpg";
        ofd.FilterIndex = 1;
        ofd.Multiselect = false;
        bool? ok = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if(ok == true)
        {
            Image loaded = new Image();
            loaded.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofd.FileName));
            loaded.Height = 100;
            this.Content = loaded;
        }
    }
```

```
<Button x:Name="BookCover" Click="ChangeImageFile">
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="Images/NewBook.png"/>
            </Button.Content>
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    ... LONG STYLE ...
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Comment: When you write `this.Content`, `this` refers to what ?

Comment: As you stated, this refers to the window and because the page was in development, no other elements existed in the window, making me unable to see that the image was the only thing left. Your solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `this.Content`, this refers to the current window and not to the button. You either need to access the button by Name or cast the sender.

**By Name:**

```
BookCover.Content = loaded;
```

**Cast the sender:**

```
Button btn = (sender as Button);
if(btn != null)
   btn.Content = loaded;
```

Comment: Could be true,  but what if OP extended the button class and performing this logic? In which case it is correct.